# How to present popover with animations?

Tags: ios, animation, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

Currently, I'm using `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` to present my popover. But I'm looking for more fanciful animations (eg. the popover expanding from a particular point) to present the popover.

I've tried searching with keywords `ios present popover animation` but can't find any useful results. Not sure if I'm using the wrong keywords or it is impossible to present popovers with animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `UIPopover`, there is currently no easy way to present it with a different animation than the one that iOS provides.  It would definitely be possible to do a custom animation to present a view, but it would be a very significant amount of extra work as you would have to do everything yourself.  Two things you could look at if you really, really need to:

1. `UIView` animation.  Links: [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial), [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) (search the page for "animation").
2. Core Animation custom transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured a way to create a simple 'animation' by using `setPopoverContentSize`. By presenting the popover with  smaller dimensions, and use `setPopoverContentSize` to expand it. Sort of an 'animation'. I guess that is the most straightforward way for now.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 7.0 it is possible to present any view controller so that it does not completely obscure the previous view controller, making it possible to create "fake" popovers. Using the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` protocol you can then create any animation you would like.

[Here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) is a good example of how to create a fake popover with a custom animation.